# JSP custom Tag or Ajax call to poulate dropdown list in a JSP

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, jakarta-ee

I need to populate drop-down list from database source, Which approach will be cleaner in terms of Design.?

JSP custom Tag: The Tag Handler class takes care of fetching data from DB and populating the list, No need to call the controller.Re usable and extensible

Ajax Call: The request have to go through Controller and not Re-usable.

Ps:Sorry,if the question looks very silly.

Comment: Ajax is mainly used if you have more than one dropdown and based one one dropdown value you need to populate another dropdown.

Comment: Thanks @VinothKrishnan.. I think I have misunderstood, why AJAX is used.